# INSERT from trigger not happening?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I'm new to triggers in PostgreSQL.
I have 3 tables in this example `table1`, `table2` and `table3`.

- The trigger fires on new record on `table1`.
- The trigger function loops through all records of `table2` that have the same `product_id` as the new record from `table1`.
- It inserts into `table3` some mixed values from the first 2 tables.
- After that, the same `INSERT` query is inserted into a test table for testing purpose.

The problem is the `INSERT` on `table3` is not happening. The `INSERT` on test table is fine and the logged insert query can be executed without troubles, so I don't know why it's not executed inside the trigger/function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_trigger() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $my_trigger$
DECLARE r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT t2.id_t2, t2.name_1, t2.name_2, t2.name_3 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.product_id=NEW.product_id 
  LOOP
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO table3 (id_t3, id_t1, name_1, name_2, name_3, bool_t2) VALUES (' || r.id_t2 || ',' || NEW.id_t1 || ', ''' || r.name_1 || ''',''' || r.name_2 || ''',''' || r.name_3 || ''', TRUE);';
    INSERT INTO test (field1, field2) VALUES(r.id_t2, 'INSERT INTO table3 (id_t3, id_t1, name_1, name_2, name_3, bool_t2) VALUES (' || r.id_t2 || ',' || NEW.id_t1 || ', ''' || r.name_1 || ''',''' || r.name_2 || ''',''' || r.name_3 || ''', TRUE);');
  END LOOP;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$my_trigger$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Edit:
As @Rachcha asked, the trigger itself is defined this way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
  AFTER INSERT
  ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger();
```

Edit 2: I've also tried to insert without `EXECUTE`, but the result is the same: no errors but no fields inserted into `table3`.

Comment: @Rachcha: yes, the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simpler function

It makes no sense to `RETURN NEW` in an `AFTER` trigger. Use `RETURN NULL` instead. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/trigger-definition.html)

> The return value is ignored for row-level triggers fired after an
> operation, and so they can return `NULL`.

No point in using a `LOOP`. Use a simple SQL statement instead.
No point in using dynamic SQL with `EXECUTE`.
This should work:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_trigger()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO table3
         (   id_t3,     id_t1,    name_1, bool_t2)
   SELECT t2.id_t2, NEW.id_t1, t2.name_1, true
   FROM   table2 t2
   WHERE  t2.product_id = NEW.product_id;

   INSERT INTO test
         (  field1, field2)
   SELECT t2.id_t2, 'INSERT ...'
   FROM   table2 t2
   WHERE  t2.product_id = NEW.product_id;

   RETURN NULL;
END
$func$;
```

Or `SELECT` from `table2` once in a CTE and use that in multiple `INSERT` commands:

```sql
...
   WITH t2 AS (
      SELECT t.id_t2, t.name_1
      FROM   table2 t
      WHERE  t.product_id = NEW.product_id
      )
   , ins_t3 AS (
      INSERT INTO table3
            (   id_t3,     id_t1,    name_1, bool_t2)
      SELECT t2.id_t2, NEW.id_t1, t2.name_1, true
      FROM   t2
      )
   INSERT INTO test
         (  field1, field2)
   SELECT t2.id_t2, 'INSERT ...'
   FROM   t2;
...
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wswKtgjp)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3d962/1)</sub>

#### Debugging

If it doesn't work, the problem is something that is not in your question. Do you have *any* other triggers or rules defined on `table1` or table `test`?

To debug, add this line to your trigger function to see if you even get there and what values are in `NEW`

```
RAISE EXCEPTION 'Values in NEW: %', NEW::text;
```

Comment: OK, good points, applied them, but still the same, no errors but row is not inserted into table 3. I ran the INSERT code in pgAdmin and it's OK, i don't know why it refuses to insert inside the function/trigger. Anyway, my code does the same thing in another (maybe less optimized) way, but it's not wrong. And i copied the code from what i typed in pgAdmin, so it's my fault that it's a mess, i'll make it prettier later, now i'm going for lunch, this thing is driving me mad. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @JohnLucabech Sorry for "complete mess". I only had a few minutes and didn't realize you are saving the `INSERT` command to test. Pretty hard to parse for the human eye. I removed that. Apart from that, what I posted should be working. I added an SQLfiddle to demonstrate and some more hints.

Comment: Well, the problem was being caused by some outdated lines in a PHP script that deleted the just inserted row(s), the trigger function was always fine, anyway, i accept your answer because it gave me a shorter, cleaner and better optimized way to do it. Thank!