# Plpgsql, how to insert a new row in multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, multiple-tables, supabase-database

I have a supabase plpgsql data base with 10 tables.  I also have the auth.users.  I'm trying to write a function which will insert a new row in each of the 10 public.tables when a new user signs up.  I have used security definer and have a function which works properly, but it will only allow me to insert into public.table1 , If I try to add other public tables to the function then it fails.

I have all RLS set to allow all, I have also tried 2 separate functions where both use a trigger from the auth.user table, with one writing to public.table1 while the other trigger and funtion write to public.table2 , however nothing seems to work.  I'm not that familiar with plpgsql, so if someone could show me the correct way to write the code, it would be greatly appreciated.  What I have now that works, but only for one public table insert is as follows

```
    Begin
      Insert into    public.tableone(id)
Values (new.id);
Returns new;
```

I'm sure there is another way to do this, such as a CTE, but I have not been able to write the code correctly to work.  I'm a beginner, so please take it easy on me guys. Lol

Comment: [plpgsql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) is the name of the server-side procedural language of PostgreSQL. You have a PostgreSQL database, "Postgres" for short. "It fails" is not telling us a whole lot. Show the verbatim error message, your version of Postgres, and the **full** code you tried (not just part of the function body). Also clarify what you want to return. `Returns new` indicates a trigger function (with syntax error) ... Also show the trigger using it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you insert into those other tables is the new ID, you don't need a CTE.

```sql
-- trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trg_users_insert_after()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO public.tableone(id) VALUES (NEW.id);
   INSERT INTO public.tabletwo(id) VALUES (NEW.id);
-- more?   

   RETURN NULL;  -- note correct syntax!
END
$func$;

-- trigger
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON public.users
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION public.trg_users_insert_after();
```

In older versions before Postgres 11 use the old (misleading) syntax:

```
...
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE ...
```

Related:

- [INSERT from trigger not happening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504827/insert-from-trigger-not-happening/15505538#15505538)

Comment: Thank you for the info, I finally found the issue, I was already using the function you provided, however on my many triggers I had for other functions, I had the trigger set to insert or update for those to fire.  Once I removed the insert part, everything worked fine.